# Replacing JSRuntime.Current in Blazor-WebAssembly

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

Working on a *somewhat non-conventional* Blazor proof-of-concept currently - trying to use Blazor WebAssembly to do data transformations on the client, within the context of a standard Javascript SPA (React).

I'm currently having an issue where the exact API I need to use has been removed - **JSRuntime.Current.** In order to perform the data transformations, I need two-way messaging between the WebAssembly module and JS. The data transformation happens in intervals using System.Timers, which means I can't just do a static method and return the processed data, but rather need to invoke the appropriate JS function at regular intervals directly.

This means I face the issue(s) of:

- If the classes and methods are dynamic, I can Inject JSRuntime into the instance but not invoke the appropriate C# methods via JS
- If the classes and methods are static, I can invoke C# via JS, but I cannot invoke the JS to return it after processing

The best solution I've been able to create so far has been PubSub messaging between static and dynamic methods - which is a completely ridiculous way to deal with this issue.

Ideas?